# Resistor requirement for 3.3 V supply

Tags: led, resistors

**Can I safely power a LED with 3.3 V without a resistor?** I have some LEDs that I typically power with 5 V and a 220 Ω resistor, but I can only supply 3.3 V at the moment.

Additionally, I have push-buttons that I typically pull-down with 10 kΩ resistors when using 5 V. What resistor should I use in this case? **Is there a general rule on what resistor should be used given the voltage?**

Comment: It depends on the LED. Some LEDs won't even light at 3.3V.

Comment: My LED can light with 3.3v, and it's about as bright as when I use 5v with the resistor

Comment: All powers sources have a service or assistance if this was a lithium ion battery primary cell you can apply it directly if this was a computer power supply you may need a resistor of about 1 to 10 ohms So that the voltage drop across the resistor is your current and the resulting voltage matches the LED specifications. For example a 5 mm one maybe 3.1 V at 20 mA so it 200 mV drop with 200 mA is 10 ohms

Comment: The general rule depends on the LED specifications.

Comment: "can I safely power a LED with 3.3v without a resistor?"  It depends. Define safely. "Is there a general rule on what resistor should be used given the voltage?" Not really. The resistance should be high enough to not use excessive current, and low enough that EMI and other disturbances won't trigger spurious button presses.

Comment: Dear misunderstood, you may not realize that my assumptions are different than yours. It is true that lithium ion is secondary and lithium is primary I meant to say secondary but 3.6 or 3.7 is more the open circuit voltage and not the mean voltage for high current as the voltage decays to 3.0 V so I prefer to say 3.3V avg and you can regulate them with this to3.3V https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/438

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt YOu said "but 3.6 or 3.7 is more the open circuit voltage and not the mean voltage for high current".  3.6 is nominal for a Li-Cobalt 18650, even at high current.  In this PDF is shows a 2C discharge curve. 2C = 6.7 Amp for this 3350mAh battery.  3.2V is the the discharge cutoff voltage for a 3.6V Li-ion. 3.0V is considered too deep of a discharge and can be damaged if allowed to discharge to 2.8V.  Notice where in the curve is 3.6V, certainly NOT open circuit! See the red 0.5C discharge curve, where 1.625 amps is flowing and the voltage is 3.6V at mid-point discharge

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt here is the datasheet:  https://na.industrial.panasonic.com/sites/default/pidsa/files/panasonic-ncr18650bf-datasheet.pdf

Comment: You are ignoring Panasonic’s capacity spec which shows in the graph a 2C starting at 3.7V and cutoff at 2.5V so the mean Vbat=3.1 approx but I agree 100% DOD is bad for aging yet this is how it is spec’d. A compromise might be 90%DoD to 2.9 V so (3.7+2.9)/2 =3.3 which is what I said in the 1st place for high currents !!!

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt  But you said "but 3.6 or 3.7 is more the open circuit voltage". You can't just change the subject.  Sure you can DoD to 100% and reduce cycle life down to 300 cycles. I'll take back the 2.8V discharge that may have been only for an  Li-aluminum or Li-phosphate. I do not remember where I read that. But another Panasonic battery (likely a  Li-manganese used for power tools) and a 3.0V cutoff: https://na.industrial.panasonic.com/sites/default/pidsa/files/ur18650zta.pdf  Hopefully you at least agree that 3.6 is not an "open circuit" voltage after all that was the point

Comment: Yes I agree,my bad,  hopefully you can agree to understand how LED ESR = 1/Pmax and how that affects current derated forward drop Vf with a tolerance   + 50% on older power LEDs and poor quality 5mm and -50% on the best quality high power diodes (any kind including BJT’s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick answer

If you were using to 220 ohms from 5 V and you drop the supply to 3.3 for a 2.1V RED then 5-2.1=2.9 or R reduces to 2.9/220*R=1.2V difference

and R=1.2 /2.9×220= answer

Very accurate method which I use to estimate R and determine the voltage threshold for dim at 10% Imax  which is often 10% below the rated forward voltage .  Then use the difference voltage between the supply and that threshold Vt to determine the total series resistance.

The LED resistance is I have found inverse to its power rating so a 1/16W is ~ 16 ohms , a 1 W is approximately 1 ohms or less. Thus the added Series R changes with power of the LED.

This may sound complicated but with practice it’s trivial. The total series resistance you would need to drop from 3.3 V just depends on the LED curve ESR plus the series resistance to get exact desired current with reasonable tolerances. If you search my answers in the window at the top of this page you will find I have written dozens of examples on this topic.

Also compute I^2R for high current LEDs

You may learn how to do this or not is your choice.

E.g. in search tab above type or paste  [user:"Tony Stewart" LED ESR R](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A%22Tony%20Stewart%22%20LED%20ESR%20R)
quote marks are needed due to space in "my name" . I see I have 63 hits for these keywords.

For users wanting to check self, enter "user:me" .... key words

Comment: I am a little confused as to where you got the 1.2V in 2.9/220*R=1.2V

Comment: Red Vf=2.1  Vcc=3.3  new difference = 1.2  old difference was 2.9  . I can put that into a ratio formula for scaling know R values  or you can try to follow my general rule in answer for any situation.  The result is the same with I=Vdrop/R where R can be on either side of the LED. Then in fancier high power methods current can be sensed on the low side and regulated with a comparator or difference amplifier.

Comment: Alright, so if I had 5v go to 2.2v after passing through an LED, I  the resistance I should use on that same LED with 3.3v would be 1.1/2.8*220 ≈ 94Ω?

Comment: You got it.  Vcc ≈ IR+ Vf = I*94Ω +2.1V= 3.3V so If≈13 mA, which is ok?  but since ESR of LED ~ 15 Ω  so can include that in the R value otherwise  1.2V drop   If = 1.2V/(94Ω+ESR)  Note that the ESR of 15 Ohms means the LED Vf drops 150mV for a drop of 10mA from rated 20mA. So minor corrections mean Vf might be 2.0V with same If=13mA,  {R+ESR}=(3.3-2.0)V/13mA= 100 Ohms = R+ESR so **R becomes 85 Ohms.** or nearest value,  This is why I use Vt in my formula. instead of Vf at rated current, where Vt is a dim thershold at 10% of rated current above which is fairly linear

Comment: as in my answer  where Vt≈90%Vf and Vf = Vt + If * (ESR+R)  ESR may also include battery ESR such as a 3.7V Li-Ion so optimum power LED's in flashlights match certain batteries to certain LEDs for cheap flashlights with no regulation, e.g. Some 10W LEDs are 2.85V at 350mA may be Vt=2.6V with ESR = 100 mΩ +0/-50%  and Li-Ion ESR may be 50 mΩ +/- xx % per cell.  The 90%Vf is an estimate but is better obtained from datasheet.

Answer (score 4):

An LED has a point where the terminal voltage applied causes a significant rise in the current taken and if you increase that voltage by even as little as 0.1 volts, the current taken by the LED could be beyond its operational rating.

Because that voltage (for your LED) might be OK set at 3.3 volts, it doesn't mean you won't blow the back off it at 3.4 volts. This is why we put a current limit resistor in series. If your LED takes 100 mA at 3.3 volts (for instance) you would need to drop 1.7 volts from 5 volts with a resistor.

That means a resistor of value 1.7 volts / 100 mA = 17 ohm.

Now, if your 5 volt rose to 5.1 volts, the 100 mA would rise to no more than 1.8 volts / 17 ohm = 106 mA. If your LED is rated at a maximum current of 120 mA, you could in fact allow the 5 volts to rise to 5.34 volts before being on the cusp of exceeding its ratings.

Do you see how adding a resistor protects your LED from over-current?

For pull-down resistors on switches you need to ensure that if there is a wetting current requirement to be met, the resistor is low enough to allow that current to flow.

Comment: Let me say thanks, i like your answers and tonight i'm lucky to see you twice during my nightly researches

Comment: So if led is rated [2.8v - 3.1v] is it ok to connect it to an ideal 3v supply without resistor?

Comment: No it isn’t. You need to control the LED current. Try googling LED voltage current characteristic.

Comment: No to your exact question @payam_sbr, but...If an LED truly does work with voltages between 2.8V-3.1V, then you are correct.  3V would be fine.  However, the voltage bounds will change over time.  So initially the 2.8-3.1 safe range may be correct, but after the LED gets warm, the safe range might change to be from 2.7V to 2.9V.  At that point, a 3V input is quite bad.  That's why in practice you need that resistor.  Its because "something" changes.  You need to know that that IV curve is going to change and do something to minimize the impact.  That resistor minimizes the impact.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot safely power most LEDs with a 3.3V source when the source can supply more current than the LED's capacity.

Two characteristics of the LED need to be known to calculate the resistor.

1. The Forward Voltage
2. The maximum current capacity

If the current output of the 3.3V source is less than the LED's maximum, then it is safe.

If you need a resistor you select your desired current which must be equal to or less than the LED's maximum current.

Today most new white LEDs driven at less than maximum (e.g. test current) will have a forward voltage of about 2.85V.  At maximum current about 3.1V.  Red LEDs are about 2.1V.

A very common current for LEDs used in lighting is 65mA. Indicator LEDs are 20-50 mA.
For an example let's use 60 mA as the target current and an LED with a 2.85V V<sub>f</sub>

You then use an LED resistor calculator the find the value of the resistor.

The resistor value is 7.5Ω for 60 mA and a 2.85 V<sub>f</sub> powered by a 3.3V source,

[image]
*Source:* [Hobby Hour LED Series Resistor Calculator](https://www.hobby-hour.com/electronics/ledcalc.php)

---

**A red indicator LED with a 220Ω resistor draws about 13 mA at 5V.
13 mA at 3.3V would use a 91.3Ω (1%) or 100Ω (5% 12mA) resistor**

[image]

[image]

Comment: These calculators have innacuracies based on user input of 2.1 @ 13mA which is incorrect, It should be reduced 7mA *ESR.  but dont take my advice.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt OP said 5V with 220Ω resistor.  The only assumption is a 2.1V red led as stated.  That works out to 13mA when powered with 5V.   Then I changed the 5V supply voltage to 3.3 leaving the 13 mA.  The calculated resistance value is then 92.3Ω.  Prior to that I explained step by step how to calculate the resistor for any LED.  ESR?  I do not need to calculate ESR.  I only need desired current and forward voltage at that current.  ESR gives me nothing. ESR will remain exactly the same at 13mA no matter what the supply voltage is.  Thanks for the down vote.

Comment: The assumption is wrong and I indicated why.  If you put blind faith into a calculator you get errors unless you understand the impact ESR has on Vf.  Capiche?

Comment: If you care to understand why I down voted , try reading my other answers on LED ESR in my links posted in my answer. When you understand let me know and I'll reverse the -1

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt  It's not "blind faith".  The math is not that difficult.  ESR is forward voltage divided by current.  LEDs have a dynamic ESR based on the current.  If the current through the LED remains the same so does the ESR.  Notice in the calculator for both 5V and 3.3V supply voltage the "power consumed by LED" remains the same. Why? The ESR remains the same so therefore forward voltage remains the same because the current remained the same as will as the power consumed.  Where did you get lost??  It not that complicated.

Comment: Sorry but you are completely wrong.  Vf(I)=Vt+ESR*I is not constant. Do not repeat this mistake.

Comment: I am not wrong!!!!   Look at section 5 Dynamic Resistance in this PDF.  http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva253a/snva253a.pdf  If the current remains the same how is dynamic resistance (i.e. ESR as you say) going to change???

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt  Look at your own calculation.  It matches the online calculator.   R=1.2 /2.9×220= answer = 91Ω

Comment: You are missing the points and completely ignoring my advanced details although I see my edited explanation is missing.  The quick answer is 91. The correct answer reduced Vf (20mA) to Vf(13) by 15 ohms (ESR) times 7mA (drop from rated) =0.1V from rated 2.1 =2.0 thus 1.3/2.9*220=~100 ohms BTW that “5W” diode is obsolete 2007 model and now ESR is closer to 0.5/ Pmax on high quality power LEDs

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt  Where are you getting 20mA?  If an LED has a supply voltage of 5V with a 220Ω resistor that means there is 13 mA flowing through the LED.  When the supply voltage is 3.3V, the resistance is 91Ω, and the current is STILL 13mA. That was the OP's question.  There is no 20mA!  ESR is not an issue when the current remains the same 13 mA.  The ESR is not going to change a significant amount between 13 mA and 20 mA even if there was 20mA.  And what 5W diode?  We have a 27.3 mW LED.  Not exactly a a "power diode".  Where are you?

Comment: You still don’t get it ...typ spec is red Vf=2.1@20mA thus Vf=2V @13mA not 2.1.  Lookup Zzt for zeners it is identical to my formula Vzt =Vz+If*Zzt. Where I call Zzt the ESR but they call it the zener threshold impedance(Z)

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt So what?  The OP said he typically drove his LED at 13 mA (5V and 220Ω).  And the question was what resistance would be used if the supply voltage were changed from 5V to 3.3V.  20 mA was never mentioned.  2.1V is an assumption based on that the majority of red LEDs are 2.1V at test current even for high power LEDs. Examples: Luminus  SST-90-R-F11-HJ102 2.1V @ 3100 mA 
Cree XPERED-L1-R250-00202  2.1V @ 350 mA  So what if there is a 2.1V 20mA LED?  20mA is not typical.  20 mA NOT relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. As an electronics technician for over 2 decades and about 35 years as a hobbyist, the engineers are of course going way out of their way to over-engineer a simple series resistor for an indicator LED...

Having had real world experience with LEDs for my entire adult life - I have never seen a failed LED that was due to over-voltage or over current that wasn't just a stupid mistake, like leaving out a resistor all together.

The vast majority of indicator LEDs have a wide operating current curve and will not fail for a simple transient condition. I have seen a lot of burnt boards due to trying to do things like dissipate 10's of watts in order to drive a 1.2Vf LED from too high of a voltage source.

The simple rule of thumb that I use and has yet to fail me yet is 470 ohms for 5-volt sources and 220 ohms for 3.3v.

I will error on the side of lower current sometimes, just for less light output so I'm not blinding someone or the power budget calls for it. Things like laser or certain IR diodes require a closer look, but they are often pulsed and you have to take Ipeak and Iave into account.

The math is useful in some cases, yes, but the boots on the ground truth is that it's often just as useful to have the "99% of use cases" stored away in the ol' file cabinet between your ears... Some people have a different opinions on how they like to spend their time, though. Cite whitepapers and down vote all you want, some of us work on actual hardware for a living and have seen what 99% of design engineers turn to.